# Ajustar lista de produtos no woocommerce, para ficar alinhados corretamente

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, woocommerce, layout

Minha loja está com o seguinte visual

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu gostaria de alinhar corretamente os produtos, pois o visual não está legal.

Como conseguiria fazer isso?

Comment: Vc está usando boostrap? Só com a imagem fica difícil te ajudar. A página já está publicada, vc tem o link?

Comment: Estou usando o Tema AccessPress Store do Woocommerce, não estou usando bootstrap @hugocsl , e ainda não está publicada, está em fase de manutenção

Comment: Vc já tem o link da página? Mas já te adianto que o problema é pq cada produto tem um tamanho de texto. Se vc colocar todos os textos com mesmo tamanho não tera problema. Falo do texto verde na descriçaõ do produto, uns tem 2 linhas, outros 4 linhas, se todos tiverem 2 ou se todos tiverem 4 acho que não vai dar problema. Mas para resolver sem o código não da...

Comment: @hugocsl, era isso mesmo o problema, ja foi solucionado, se quiser colocar como resposta eu aceito ela

Comment: Valeu a força Tiago, deixei uma resposta com mais detalhes e um exemplo pra vc testar e ver melhor pq essa quebra acontece. []'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago muito provavelmente seu Grid é baseado em Floats por isso ele está quebrando.

Resumindo meio que grosseiramente, quando os elementos não têm a mesma altura *(no seu caso quando cada produto tem um tamanho de texto)* o encaixe dos elementos uma abaixo do outro não da certo e o layout quebra.

Fiz esse exemplo pra vc entender melhor e ver a quebra e como corrigi-la. *No seu caso para corrigir basta colocar a descrição de todos os itens com a mesma quantidade de linhas, obtendo a altura igual para todos.*

**OBS:** Deixei os comentários no código

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
    height: 50px; /* todos os itens devem ter a mesma altura  */
    background-color: aquamarine;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 55px; /* esse item com a altura diferente faz seu layout quebrar  */
}
```

```html
<div>height: 50px;</div>
<div>esse tem altura diferente height: 55px;</div>
<div>height: 50px;</div>

<div>height: 50px;</div>
<div>height: 50px;</div>
<div>height: 50px;</div>
```